# Remove a single item from cart in php

Tags: php, session, cart

I am trying to remove a single item from cart.php , it wont work . What should I do ? This is my code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$item_id = $_GET["item_id"];

session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION["incart"])) {

    foreach($_SESSION["incart"] as $select => $val) {  

        unset($_SESSION["incart"]);

    }

}
?>
```

print_r output

```
Array (
        [0] => Array ( 
            [item_id] => 100002
            [item_name] => Porsche
            [item_price] => 200
            [item_img] => porsche.jpg
            [nowdate] => 40
            [enddate] =>60
         )
)
```

Comment: I suspect you are dropping the full cart but do not know without seeing what the stored data looks like,  use this to print it out a formatted array then update the question with it formatted the same way. echo "<pre">; print_r($_SESSION['incart']); echo "</pre">;

Comment: I tried doing it like this

Comment: <?php
$item_id = $_GET["item_id"];
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION["incart"])) {
foreach($_SESSION["incart"] as $select => $val)
{  
if ($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_id"] == $item_id){
 unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_id"]);
  unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_name"]);
   unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_price"]);
    unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["item_img"]);
     unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["inowdate"]);
      unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]["enddate"]);





 
 
}
}
}
 ?>

Comment: it worked but ,,the style and the table remains ,, thats confusing O.o

Comment: You dont need to unset them individually, if you want to drop an item, incart $select is as far as you go because its an array, you are basically unsetting the full array for that cart line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$item_id = $_GET["item_id"];
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION["incart"])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION["incart"] as $select => $val) {
        if($val["item_id"] == $item_id)
        {
            unset($_SESSION["incart"][$select]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I was just commenting basically this then i saw your answer. +1.